# Jmeter include controller relative path

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

We are using Jmeter-maven-plugin and created a maven project in eclipse. My test file (MainTest.jmx) is in src/test/jmeter folder, in this test we used "include controller" to reuse test fragments. These fragments are stored in src/test/jmeter/fragments. We tried following relative path in include controller

1. ../fragments/FragmentA.jmx
2. src/test/jmeter/fragments/FragmentA.jmx
3. Tried propertiesUser option in pom.xml

```html
<propertiesUser>
                <fragments.directory>src/test/jmeter/fragments</fragments.directory>
</propertiesUser>
```

Include controller failing to load .jmx file. Getting following

> ERROR
>   o.a.j.c.IncludeController: Include Controller 'Include Controller'
>   can't load '${__P(fragments.directory)}/fragmentA.jmx' - see log for
>   details.
>
> java.io.IOException: loadIncludedElements -failed for:
>   E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\bin\${__P(fragments.directory)}\FragmentA.jmx and E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\testFiles\${__P(fragments.directory)}\FragmentA.jmx

Complete Log

```html
> 2017-05-24 12:14:39,442 INFO o.a.j.c.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\bin\FragmentA.jmx
> 2017-05-24 12:14:39,442 INFO o.a.j.c.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -failed for: E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\bin\FragmentA.jmx
> 2017-05-24 12:14:39,442 INFO o.a.j.c.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -Attempting to read it from: E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\testFiles\FragmentA.jmx
> 2017-05-24 12:14:39,442 ERROR o.a.j.c.IncludeController: Include Controller 'Include Controller' can't load 'FragmentA.jmx' - see log for details
> 2017-05-24 12:14:39,443 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Including file "FragmentA.jmx" failed for Include Controller "Include Controller", unexpected error - see log for details
> 2017-05-24 12:14:39,443 WARN o.a.j.c.IncludeController: Including file "FragmentA.jmx" failed for Include Controller "Include Controller", unexpected error
> java.io.IOException: loadIncludedElements -failed for: E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\bin\FragmentA.jmx and E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\testFiles\FragmentA.jmx
> at org.apache.jmeter.control.IncludeController.loadIncludedElements(IncludeController.java:139) [ApacheJMeter_components-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
> at org.apache.jmeter.control.IncludeController.resolveReplacementSubTree(IncludeController.java:111) [ApacheJMeter_components-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
> at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:936) [ApacheJMeter_core-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
> at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:910) [ApacheJMeter_core-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
> at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:538) [ApacheJMeter_core-3.2.jar:3.2 r1790748]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) prior to attempting to use Include Controller this way?

> This element **does not support variables/functions in the filename field**.
>   However, if the property includecontroller.prefix is defined, the contents are used to prefix the pathname.

The same chapter provides the clue: you have `includecontroller.prefix` property and JMeter will attempt to find the file under the path of `includecontroller.prefix` + `Filename`

So you should amend your configuration as follows:

```
<propertiesUser>                
    <includecontroller.prefix>src/test/jmeter/fragments</includecontroller.prefix>
</propertiesUser>
```

And use just `FragmentA.jmx` in the Include Controller.

Check out [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) for more information on working with modular JMeter tests.

Comment: Still it trying to find file in target/jmeter/bin folder                                              
         > 2017-05-24 12:14:39,442 INFO o.a.j.c.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\bin\FragmentA.jmx
> 2017-05-24 12:14:39,442 INFO o.a.j.c.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -failed for: E:\Luna\ADXJmeter\target\jmeter\bin\FragmentA.jmx                                     > 2017-05-24 12:14:39,442 ERROR o.a.j.c.IncludeController: Include Controller 'Include Controller' can't load 'FragmentA.jmx' - see log for details

Comment: It worked after adding following                                                                           <includecontroller.prefix>${basedir}/target/jmeter/testFiles/fragments/</includecontroller.prefix> in pom.xml

Comment: I have binaries so I added the desired path in my jmeter.properties file but it didn't work. In the logs, I saw the include controller was pointing to the bin folder every time. So, instead of making it complicated I just added "..\scripts\call.jmx" path in the Filename because my "call.jmx" script file is under "jmeter3.3\scripts\call.jmx" and script folder is sibling of bin folder so moving out of bin folder entered in scripts folder made it work. Might be useful for someone.

Comment: Quick tip for windows users, don't forget to double backslash eg:

D:\\mypath\\myjmeter\\

Also remember to add trailing backslash!