# How do I avoid random "o.a.j.c.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -failed for:" errors in Blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have an include controller that has a property like this...

```
<stringProp name="IncludeController.includepath">../SSO/SSOLoginGroup.jmx</stringProp>
```

It seems to run fine locally and on the server, however, when I put it under load I see random errors like this...

> o.a.j.c.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -failed for: /home/jmeter/../SSO/SSOLoginGroup.jmx

I see some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133553/jmeter-include-controller-relative-path) that suggests something like this...

```
<stringProp name="IncludeController.prefix">SSO</stringProp>
<stringProp name="IncludeController.includepath">SSOLoginGroup.jmx</stringProp>
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.

The other strange thing is that this is all in a if controller that should be turned off anyway.

How do I include relative paths in Blazemeter?

**Update**

The suggestion was made to somehow combine the folders. This doesn't really work given my structure, I have multiple "parts" of the site that interact together (think admin to add an item then a customer portal to view). Because of this I would like to have the tests in shared folders that can reference back and forth and be reused in other test configurations.

Answer (score 0):

1. The easiest solution is to move your `SSO.jmx` file to the same place where your main JMX script lives. This way you will be able to reference it by name only.
2. Second recommended step is reaching out [BlazeMeter Support](https://www.blazemeter.com/support) as my expectation is that they know their infrastructure better than anyone else.

---

3. If for some reason you have to include the file from another folder i.e. for compatibility with your local setup or version control system layout - upload it to [Shared Folders](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420175-Uploading-Files-Shared-Folders)

[image: BlazeMeter Shared Folders]

The contents of the Shared Folders is being copied to all slave machines so you will be able to reference it in the main script as:

[image: JMeter Main Script Include Controller]

So your final configuration should look like:

[image: Blazemeter shared folder relative path]

Comment: I do have to keep the structure because the SSO folder for instance is used by both admin and portal tests. Otherwise I would have to have a copy in each folder or on big unorganized mess :-)

Comment: Also there are multiple references back and forth so I can't really just have it in a local upload. Then again I would have the same file uploaded all over on the Blazemeter server (once per test that uses it.)

Comment: Also can't find an email for blazemeter technical support. Just a link to their sales department.